# How to sign up using phone with OTP in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I wan to integrate phone sign up on a Ruby on Rails API with a one time pin sent to user. Are there any gems I can check out to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/stas/otp-jwt which adds helper methods to handle OTP in Ruby on Rails.

And https://github.com/knadh/otpgateway which implements OTP as a small standalone server.